# Multiple IF EXISTS statements to go up levels

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query that selects a specific value if it exists, and then it goes up a level if it doesn't exist, else it selects another record.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT top 1 * from tblDiscounts where ItemType_Fkey = 5176 order by EntryDate desc) 
BEGIN
    SELECT top 1 * from tblDiscounts where ItemType_Fkey = 5176 order by EntryDate desc
END    
ELSE IF EXISTS (SELECT discount_fkey from tblItems where ID = (select Item_Fkey from tblItemType where ID = 5176)) 
BEGIN
    select * from tblDiscounts where ID = (SELECT discount_fkey from tblItems where ID = (select Item_Fkey from tblItemType where ID = 5176))
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    select top 1 * from tblDiscounts where ID NOT IN (select Discount_Fkey from tblItems) and ItemType_Fkey is null
END
```

I think this query can slow down the performance significantly. Is there a better way to achieve the same result that is more efficient? Hope someone leads me in the right direction.

Comment: My opinion is : 1st remove the 'order by' in the first if exists (it makes no real sense if you think about it) 2nd try to remove all subqueries and use joins. Subqueries always slow the performance, if you can avoid them that would be really helpful, and from what I can see, you can easily avoid them :)

Comment: @Nissus sub-queries certainly do not always slow performance and often perform exactly the same as a join. As with all things performance and SQL Server related, performance has to be measured on a specific system.

Comment: @DaleK no i'm not really experiencing performance issues currently on the development environment. i was thinking if this gets deployed and the amount of records increases significantly.

Comment: Just to add to the comment from @Nissus, there's no reason to have `top 1` in a check for existence. You can just say `if exists (select * from ...)`. No need for `top` or `order by`, especially since the engine will almost certainly ignore those constructs anyway. It's just cruft in the query text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the simplicity of your query, and the fact that you are calling it with a single `@id` its debatable whether the performance needs to be improved. However given T-SQL works better with set-based solutions, one way to solve this kind of problem is to use `order by` to get the highest priority result first e.g.

```
select top 1 *
from tblDiscounts
order by
    -- Highest priority condition
    case when ItemType_Fkey = @Id then 1 else 0 end desc
    -- Second highest priority condition
    , case when ID = (select discount_fkey from tblItems where ID = (select Item_Fkey from tblItemType where ID = @Id)) then 1 else 0 end desc
    -- Third highest priority condition
    , case when ID not in (select Discount_Fkey from tblItems) and ItemType_Fkey is null then 1 else 0 end
    -- And then use the latest one matching our criteria
    , EntryDate desc;
```

In order to debug this, place the `order by` calculations in the query and remove the `top 1` as this will allow you to see the logic working and tweak it if necessary e.g.

```
select *
    -- Highest priority condition
    , case when ItemType_Fkey = @Id then 1 else 0 end
    -- Second highest priority condition
    , case when ID = (select discount_fkey from tblItems where ID = (select Item_Fkey from tblItemType where ID = @Id)) then 1 else 0 end
    -- Third highest priority condition
    , case when ID not in (select Discount_Fkey from tblItems) and ItemType_Fkey is null then 1 else 0 end
    -- And then use the latest one matching our criteria
    , EntryDate
from tblDiscounts
order by
    -- Highest priority condition
    case when ItemType_Fkey = @Id then 1 else 0 end desc
    -- Second highest priority condition
    , case when ID = (select discount_fkey from tblItems where ID = (select Item_Fkey from tblItemType where ID = @Id)) then 1 else 0 end desc
    -- Third highest priority condition
    , case when ID not in (select Discount_Fkey from tblItems) and ItemType_Fkey is null then 1 else 0 end desc
    -- And then use the latest one matching our criteria
    , EntryDate desc;
```

Comment: at the third highest comdition, the query is returning a result where item_type fkey is not null? any idea why? it should only return results where it is null :)

Comment: Very hard for me to comment without sample data - sorry. I've given you the principle, but it may need tweaking for your specific case.